# How to stop watchPosition() Position retrieval timed out error?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, geolocation

I am developing a phonegap application that uses the current location of the device in its functionalities but when tested on Iphone the App give an error message every 60 seconds as follows: [image]

The Source code I am using to get the location is:

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    var options = { maximumAge: 0, timeout: 10000,enableHighAccuracy: false };
    var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

    function onSuccess(position) {
        if (position.coords.latitude) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("appLatitude", position.coords.latitude);
            sessionStorage.setItem("appLongitude", position.coords.longitude);
        }
        //alert(sessionStorage.getItem("appLatitude") + "&" + sessionStorage.getItem("appLongitude"));
    }

    function onError(error) {
        z.appNotification.getAlert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

}
```

How can stop that error message from prompting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to get the location once use:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

If you want to stop watching for any reason, use:

```
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
```

Comment: The app requires the get the location of the device whenever the location changes and the problem rises due to that reason. The app displays a time-out error whenever the location of the phone changes.

Comment: Calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` at a regular interval (e.g. every second) on iOS cordova app instead of using `watchPosition()` avoided getting the "timeout" error. (cordova-ios 5.1.0)